# Defining Show for functor composition

Tags: haskell, composition, functor, typeclass

My apologies if this question has already been asked. `Show` is a very common keyword that makes it hard for me to cut through noise. If I have a type defined for `functor composition` as shown below, I can't figure out how to define `Show` instance for that type:

```
newtype FComp f g a = C { unC :: f (g a) }

--- Incomplete Show definition for FComp
instance Show (FComp f g a) where
  show (C x) = "FComp" ++ show ??? --- Given a type say FComp Maybe Maybe Int, should print out "FComp Maybe Maybe Int"
```

Also:

```
$ :t show
show :: Show a => a -> String
```

So, it seems show takes a value, and returns the corresponding string. Plugging `x` in `show ???` won't work since `Show` instance still needs to be defined for type `f (g a)`.

Comment: `newtype FComp f g a = C { unC :: f (g a) } deriving Show`; use GHC's `-ddump-deriv` flag to see what code it generated if you're interested.

Comment: Shouldn't it display the value, not the type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, and you would just add that as a constraint for your instance

```
instance (Show (f (g a))) => Show (FComp f g a) where
  show (C f) = "FComp " ++ show f
```

This just means we have a show instance for `FComp` exactly when we have one for `f (g a)`

You also will need to enable `-XFlexibleContexts` for this to work, but I wouldn't worry about this, it's just relaxing the restriction on what GHC allows for contexts and is pretty noncontroversial.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `show (C f) = "FComp" ++ show f` and `ghci` is telling me I need to enable `FlexibleContexts`

Comment: @dg123, yes. And go ahead and enable FlexibleContexts -- it's one of the usual extensions.

Comment: @dg123 Yes and yes, don't worry about flexiblecontexts, it's just relaxing a pretty arbitrary restriction